# Can we prevent ourself of instanciating a Java class from an imported library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deprecated

I have a library class, that is, a class that I load from a JAR, the source code is outside of my control. We instanciate it in our project in several places, and a property of the created objects should be always set. Unfortunately there is no central settings for the library, so I have created a subclass:

```
public class MyClass extends LibraryClass {
    public MyClass() {
        super();
        super.setSomeProperty();
    }
}
```

and then I replaced all instanciation of LibraryClass with MyClass. It works fine, but I want to prevent myself and my collegues to instanciate a LibraryClass in the future.

Is it possible to mark the LibraryClass (or its constructor) as deprecated by Maven or by Eclipse or somehow else? It would be a compile time solution.

Or is it possible to use some Spring/Aop magic to replace all instancieated LibraryClass with MyClass in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention to mark the constructor as deprecated (which would not actually forbid it) - if you are using something like sonar, you could create an own rule which marks the usage as error, exept for your subclass.

Comment: Thank youz, it is a good tip, we are introducing Jenkins, I try to create such a rule!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring in your application and all bean instantiation is done through Spring, on application startup check if a bean exist of type `LibraryClass`. Throw an exception if it exists. Similar solution can be implemented for any other framework used for bean instantiation.

Comment: Unfortunately the class I mean is a GUI component, it won't be instantiated by Spring, and it is not a singleton, it will be instantiated later than the appliation startup.